# Manual Fulltext index population time in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, full-text-search

I would like to know if there is a way to see how much time did it take SQL Server 2012 to index all the data in a table?

In my example I create the table, create the index and set the population to be manual. Then I execute

```
ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX ON table_name START UPDATE POPULATION;
```

The query executes immediately but as I know, the population process is actually performed in the background. How can I find out what's the total time it took to index the whole table?

Comment: I don't know if this helps, but are you aware the population process is logged?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142575.aspx#crawl has details for SQL Server 2012

Comment: Thanks, the log files contained start time and end time of population which is what I was looking for.